# I Cant Close datareader connection in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i made an listview for all poeple who scanned their ID in the system. Everything is working while I was doing the listview code however when I go back. If I log into my administrator account I found out that there is still an active connection however I traced back my code yet i have not yet found an open connection. This is my code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Public Class admin

```
Private Sub admin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ConnectToDB()
    Dim il = New ImageList()
    sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring  ORDER BY lname ASC"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    While dr.Read
        newLine = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))
    End While

  

    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    dr.Close()
    ConnectToDB()
    Dim il = New ImageList()
    sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where floor_level = 1 ORDER BY lname ASC"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    While dr.Read
        newLine = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))
    End While

    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    dr.Close()
    ConnectToDB()
    Dim il = New ImageList()

    sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where floor_level = 2 ORDER BY lname ASC"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    While dr.Read
        newLine = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))
    End While
    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    dr.Close()
    ConnectToDB()
    Dim il = New ImageList()
    sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring where floor_level = 3 ORDER BY lname ASC"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    While dr.Read
        newLine = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))
    End While

    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()



End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    dr.Close()
    ConnectToDB()
    Dim il = New ImageList()
    sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring ORDER BY lname ASC"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    While dr.Read
        newLine = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))
    End While

    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    dr.Close()
    ConnectToDB()
    Dim il = New ImageList()
    sql = "select * from rfidmaintest.monitoring ORDER BY lname ASC "
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    While dr.Read
        newLine = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        newLine.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))
    End While

    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    dr.Close()
    ConnectToDB()
    Dim listitems As ListViewItem
    sql = " SELECT * FROM monitoring WHERE lname like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    While dr.Read
        listitems = ListView1.Items.Add(dr("id_num"))
        listitems.SubItems.Add(dr("fname"))
        listitems.SubItems.Add(dr("lname"))
        listitems.SubItems.Add(dr("status"))
        listitems.SubItems.Add(dr("entry_record"))
        listitems.SubItems.Add(dr("floor_level"))
        listitems.SubItems.Add(dr("date"))

    End While

    cmd = Nothing
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I'm not going to search through the code to try to find where you may have left a reader open. It should never happen because you should ALWAYS create both the connection and the data reader with `Using` statements, in which case they will be closed implicitly at the end of the block so you can't possibly leave them open. Change your code to do that and the issue will disappear without your having to find it.

Comment: An open reader is something quite different to an open connection.  I would question the ConnectToDB() and would suspect that is the root of your issue.  Much like other comment DB connections should also be created with a Using block with will implicitly close connections.

Comment: I have put an.. Dr and cn. Close() in the very first line and it fixed my problem. Thanjs